# WCF: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException

Tags: c#, wcf

I created a simple WCF service In solution and added a console application project to the solution to call the WCF service. When i debug chat solution it give me the following error. The WCF service was working fine when i tested it.

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(EvalService));
```

Resulting error:

> A child element named 'service' with same key already exists at the
>   same configuration scope. Collection elements must be unique within
>   the same configuration scope (e.g. the same application.config file).
>   Duplicate key value:  'EvalServiceLibrary.EvalService'.
>   (C:\Users\User_Name\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\ChatSolution\ConsoleHost\bin\Debug\ConsoleHost.vshost.exe.Config
>   line 14)

Comment: Can you **SHOW US** the config file in question??

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, but in my case I was creating a service using a previously used name. Sometimes, even if you delete the service file/code from the solution, its corresponding definition in the `App.Config` file remains un-updated.

I did a Quick Find (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) over the whole solution and typed the name of the service I was using. It located the piece of code in the `App.Config` file where the service is defined.

I deleted it and created the service using the same name.

Answer (score 0):

It's all written in the exception message. You have two services in your app.config defined with the same key. Just look through the app.config in your console app, it shouldn't be hard to find.